# Compare two Excel columns, output cells in A that do not appear in B

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare two columns in excel, A and B. Column A contains a complete list of customer numbers. Column B contains an incomplete list of the same customer numbers. So if a customer number is in A, but not in B then output that number to column C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `MATCH` function in combination with `ISNA`.

If I have the following table

```
A       B       C
1       4   
2       3   
3       1   
4       7   
5       2       5
6               6
7
```

I put in column 'A' the full customer list, and in column B is a random ordered partial list. I then put the function in C1 (and the rest of column C):

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),A1, "")`

Now I see the values '5' and '6' only in column C, because those are the only two numbers that don't appear in column B.

Answer (score 0):

In Cel C1 =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$10,1,FALSE)),A1,"")

Adjust for row counts and fill down against column A.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B1,0)),A1,"")
```

Propegate that formula along your new column and it'll reprint the populated Column A when Column B is a no match.

Reference URL:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213367

(I believe I read the original question wrong, and am going on the assumption that column A and B are already sorted where the values will line up.)